# Reinstalled samba, now nautulus doesn't have network share context menu item

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, samba

After fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 I had some trouble with my Samba shares, and tried to reinstall samba as per [this thread](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/samba-in-14-04-broken/1301/17).  Now the share folder to network context menu is gone.  No tab for Network share, when selecting a folder -> Properties.

How can I get it back?

Samba seems to be running, and logging out and in again doesn't seem to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to install
[nautilus-share](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nautilus-share/) [image: Install nautilus-share]
package.

Install it using

`sudo apt-get install nautilus-share`.

Comment: Installing nautilus-share and logging out and in again fixed it. Thanks.